# Clarifying solution for algorithm

Tags: algorithm, binary

I'm working on a problem that goes as follows:

"Write a function that adds two numbers. You should not use + or any arithmetic operators."

In base 10, to add two numbers, you can split the addition process into two steps:

1) Addition without carry

2) Only the carried over values

Add the two together. The solution essentially does this, but recurses on the value of 1) and value of 2) until there aren't any more carried values. I don't understand the intuition for this--how do we know that eventually carried over values will be zero?

Below is the solution:

```
int Add(int x, int y)
{
    if (y == 0)
        return x;
    else
        return Add( x ^ y, (x & y) << 1);
}
```

Comment: Observe that `(x & y) << 1` always has at least one more zero on the right hand side than `y` did, and that's the new `y`. Therefore eventually one of the recurrences has a `y` that's zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we're using an integer representation with a fixed number of bits (e.g., 32-bit integers), then we can reason as follows:

In any given call to `Add`, let's say that `y` ends in *n* zero-valued bits. (For example, if `y`'s binary representation ends in `1000`, then *n* is 3.)

Then `x & y` ends in *at least n* zero-valued bits, since it will have zero-valued bits wherever `y` does.

And `(x & y) << 1` ends in at least *n* + 1 zero-valued bits, because it shifts everything leftward and adds a zero bit to the end. (Exception: if `y == 0`, then the number of zero bits is "maxed out", and this shift is a no-op. But in that case we wouldn't reach the `else` anyway.)

So each recursive call increases the number of trailing zero-valued bits by at least one. Since we've assumed that there's a fixed number of bits, this means that `y` will eventually become zero as nonzero bits get shifted off the start.

---

As it happens, the algorithm is still correct even if we use an unsigned-integer representation that allows an unbounded number of bits, but in that case it's a bit trickier to show. The key observations are that:

- The above argument, that each recursive call increases the number of trailing zero-valued bits in `y`, still holds. So if `y` *doesn't* eventually become zero, then it must grow without bound.
- The sum of `x` and `y` is unchanged from one recursive call to the next; and `x` never becomes negative (since the integer representation doesn't even support that); so `y` can never come to exceed that sum.

These two facts, taken together, show that `y` must eventually become zero.